# Git Push error :unpack failed: error Out of memory loading unknown object

Tags: git

I tried pushing new branch to the git repo with large files and it's failing after 39% completed saying

```
error: unpack failed: error Out of memory loading unknown object
```

I tried these as well:

```
git config pack.packSizeLimit 20m
git config pack.windowMemory 10m
```

still no luck, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the size of the large files?

Comment: Thanks for the response, The large file size is 1.31 GB

Comment: Did you try to increase the memory of JVM